# Getting nearest gps locations from a sql server if a condition is true

Tags: php, android, sql, json, gps

i'm developing android app to find nearest clients from my location if an condition is met.

To get the nearest clients I used the php code that is in below link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1#findnearsql

It works great and shows me all the nearest clients. But the problem is,

1) I only want to get clients that have service_status enum set to 1 (table is in below link),

http://i46.photobucket.com/albums/f108/ncbdrck/Capture_zps0d77ba64.png

2) I also want to get the selected raws into a JSON array instead of an XML so i can send them to my app to display in a list view.

Thanks,
Navoda

Comment: What have you tried? Can you paste some snippets of the code corresponding to the feature you're requesting help with?

Comment: It seem like the obvious answer would be to change the database query that gets the data then also change the PHP to convert it to JSON data instead of XML. **This is not a free coding service** show what you have done and explain in detail what needs changing and what new output you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the query accordingly: (*WHERE service_status = 1*)

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers WHERE service_status = 1 HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20");
```

Now, to make JSON instead of XML, just build an array with the results

```
$response = array();
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $response[] = $row;    
}

header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
header('Content-Type: application/json');    

echo json_encode($response);
```